# Search WooCommerce Products in WordPress

Tags: search, plugins

I've noticed that my WooCommerce products are not searched by the default WordPress search function. Any idea how to modify the function to ensure that products and product tabs are searched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just extend your search form with a hidden input: (notice the last input field)

```
<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
    <label>
        <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php echo _x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?></span>
        <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search …', 'placeholder' ) ?>" value="<?php echo get_search_query() ?>" name="s" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search for:', 'label' ) ?>" />
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type" id="post_type" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm running several WooCommerce sites, and the WordPress search does include products along with posts/pages. Do you have a custom `search.php` file or any custom functions that would alter the products taxonomy to exclude it from search? WooCommerce also has a product widget that can be used as well.

Comment: I'll check out the search.php file. The theme is sentient by WooThemes. I know for a fact that it's not searching the products but is searching pages and posts as I've tested it extensively. I have another site that runs the theme Mystile (again by WooThemes) and I noticed that the product search bar only seems to search products, not pages or posts.

Comment: This may be a bug withing WooCommerce then. If you contact woothemes, their support is amazing and they may be able to help you if it is a but with WC or their themes.

Answer (score -1):

You can usually specify the post type in `WP_Query`.

- Woocommerce is `product`
- Wordpress posts is `post`

Comment: Some example with explanation would be great.

Comment: Given that the original poster did not post source code, I didn't feel the need to make an effort either.

Comment: Down-voted for...